# Permission - android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE PlayStore

Tags: android, permissions, google-play

I would like to know, if this *'permission:android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'* is written in the manifest, what will be written in the permission details on the play store ?

It's when i click on "View Details" under "Permission" on an app page on the google play store.

Comment: Why don't you check it out yourself.

Comment: Because i don't have an application and i needed to know without releasing any applications.

Comment: You can check it out for other application which read/write to your storage.

Comment: Does it write in both category Storage and Photos/Media/Files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this page they describe in a public question the listing of permisions:

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/71802/help-understanding-whatsapps-permissions

and they quote for external storage permision description:

> Photos/Media/Files

modify or delete the contents of your USB storage
test access to protected storage

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect  !

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to write anything, the message shown for each permission, is shown by Google, not the developer.

Answer (score 1):

Some of my apps use `permission:android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Then on the app page of the google play store, I have this: [image]

Comment: Thank you, that is also what i wanted.

Comment: Does it write in both category Storage and Photos/Media/Files ?

Comment: Yes in both category @Delfalso

Answer (score 1):

it would be

> Strorage
>
> - modify or delete the contents of your USB storage